# Unboundid LDAP SDK - how to process an attribute value consisting of several values?

Tags: java, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk, directory-server

If you have an attribute which value consists of a comma-separated list of values, which would be the best way to retrieve some part of that value?

Example:

> myAttribute: value1, value2, value3, value4

So far, I've used regular expressions to do this, but this seems wrong somehow (because I feel there could be a better solution).

I'm using Unboundid LDAP SDK for accessing the LDAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Portions* of an LDAP attribute value cannot be retrieved. The attribute has a value, and that value is returned to the LDAP client. Perhaps your `myAttribute` should be multi-valued:

```
dn: cn=the entry,dc=example,dc=com
myAttribute: value1
myAttribute: value2
myAttribute: value3
myAttribute: value4
```

If this does not suit your application, then `StringTokenizer` or `java.util.regex` will work to split the values.